# Different results with graph_from_data_frame and graph.edgelist , igraph R package

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

I am builiding a network graph but I get different nodes counts using graph_from_data_frame and graph.edgelist.

I have a dataframe of nodes and edges, and this is what I am getting.

```
g1 <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edge_attrib, vertices = node_attrib, directed = TRUE)
Nodes<-vcount(g1) 
Edges<-ecount(g1)

Nodes
[1] 4875

Edges
[1] 17119
```

And when I use graph.edgelist I get this:

```
g1 <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(edge_attrib[,1:2]), directed=T) 
Nodes<-vcount(g1) 
Edges<-ecount(g1) 

Nodes
[1] 2963

Edges
[1] 17119
```

I don't know what could be the problem, because the nodelist has 4875 nodes.

Comment: Dear Oscar, can you provide some more details of your underlying dataframe? the dimensions or a reproducable example of the data.

Comment: Sure, the nodes DF has 17512 nodes and the edge DF has 177735 ties, the problem between the two commands ocurs when a I do some data manipulation with dplyr, but the thing is that after the manipulation the nodes DF   is with 4875 nodes and edges DF with 17119 contacts, not 2963 nodes as graph.edgelist give me as a node count, but now I have another doubt, this is that graph_from_data_frame give nodes with 0 total degree, which is not correct because I extract the nodes DF from muy edge DF so, every node has a contacts, rigth know I don't know what to do.